# Res.render in expressjs for rendering handlebars page is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, handlebars.js

So on my client side, I have the following javascript

```
search_button.addEventListener("click", event => {
    fetch("/api/specific-customer/" + search_input.value).then(res => {
        console.log(res.status)
    })
})
```

And then on my server side, I have the following endpoint

```
router.get("/specific-customer/:name", (req, res) => {
    let target_user = req.params.name;
    let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE customer_name = ?";
    mysql.pool.query(sqlQuery, [target_user], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(result)
            let data = {
                customer: result
            }
            res.render("index", data)
        }
    })
});
```

The res.render is not rendering the index page at all, it just does nothing. I am currently on the index page but I wanted to re render it with different data instead of the default SELECT * FROM Products. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If rendering engine is not specified then use file name with extension. like res.render("index.hbs", data).

Comment: Read this article to configure express application for handlebar templating engine https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-handlebars-view-engine-in-node-js/amp/

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL query doesn't return any errors, then here's a couple of approaches to achieving what you're looking for.

#### First Approach

- Don't use fetch on search button click event
- Just redirect with [`window.location.replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp)
- Pass the `name` to the URL

```js
search_button.addEventListener("click", event => {
   window.location.replace("/api/specific-customer/" + search_input.value);
})
```

#### Second Approach

- if there's no `target_user`, it means we're trying to render the index page without any data, so we return `res.render('index')`
- On the index page, when the search button is clicked we use `fetch` to make an API call to the same endpoint `("/specific-customer/:name")` but this time with a `target_name` as the URL param.
- Now because we're passing the `target_name`, it doesn't `res.render()` again, instead it returns the result of the SQL query as JSON.
- Finally, use the data you get to populate the page.

```js
router.get("/specific-customer/:name", (req, res) => {
  let target_user = req.params.name;

  if (!target_user) {
    return res.render('index')
  }

  let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE customer_name = ?";
    mysql.pool.query(sqlQuery, [target_user], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
            let data = {
                customer: result
            }
            res.json(data)
        }
    })
  
});
```

Comment: fetch can be used to fetch dynamic template also (ref:https://gomakethings.com/getting-html-with-fetch-in-vanilla-js/#the-fetch-text-method). So problem is no t with ```fetch``` it is on server.

Comment: That's right but this seems to be a server-side rendered app, so why use `fetch` to make a get request when you can just make the request by replacing the window location URL. Not sure I completely understand your point @MuhammadSaquibShaikh

Comment: Suppose you want to load some html code in your page, for that you will not like to reload instead of this you can pull that code from server and inject there. In that case fetch can be used to get dynamic content.

Comment: I think he has not configured his express application properly, ask him to read this article https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-handlebars-view-engine-in-node-js/amp/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

In the directory, locate the file `views/layouts/main.handlebars`

Edit it to include:

```
{{> navbar}}
{{{body}}}
{{> footer}}
```

Structure should look like this:

```
└── views
    ├── layouts
    │   └── main.handlebars
    └── partials
    │   ├── footer.handlebars
    │   └── navbar.handlebars
    └── about.handlebars
    └── home.handlebars
```

This structure worked well for me. It integrates the navbar and footer partials, while `{{{body}}}` is where your main content will be injected.